# unexpected keyword argument in qiskit vqe

Tags: qiskit, hamiltonian-simulation, vqe

I want to find the estimate of the ground state energy of my Hamiltonian `H` that is implemented as `PauliSumOp` in my variable `H_op`. I then prepare an ansatz circuit `circ_ansatz` with 5 parameters. Then I try to run the thing with
`my_vqe = VQE(ansatz = circ_ansatz, optimizer=SPSA, quantum_instance=Aer.get_backend('aer_simulator'), initial_point=[0.5]*N_iters)` and then `print(my_vqe.compute_minimum_eigenvalue(H_op))` but I get the following error:  `print(my_vqe.compute_minimum_eigenvalue(H_op)) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/algorithms/minimum_eigen_solvers/vqe.py", line 526, in compute_minimum_eigenvalue opt_result = self.optimizer(  # pylint: disable=not-callable TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fun'`

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my_vqe = VQE(ansatz = circ_ansatz, optimizer=SPSA,...

You need to make an instance of the optimizer not pass the class (set any parameters you want the following uses defaults)

my_vqe = VQE(ansatz = circ_ansatz, optimizer=SPSA(),...